# Можно ли скомпилировать Python код в C, C++ или C#

Tags: c#, c++, python-3.x, c, компиляция

У меня есть код на Python, но он работает довольно медленно, и мне надо, чтобы он работал максимально быстро.

У меня программа постоянно делает скриншот ImageGrab.Grab (Pillow) и ищет белые пиксели в определенной области, а дальше если их количество превышает 90000, то выполняет пару кликов. Использую Pillow, Numpy, Win32api, threading

Comment: В первую очередь подумайте — тот ли алгоритм используется? Нет ли более быстрого?

Comment: Ну не то чтобы медленно работает, но для задачи надо, чтобы еще быстрее. Я использую библиотеки написанные на C++ и многопоточность, даже не знаю куда быстрее, если и можно, но сильного прироста не будет думаю.

Comment: Можно налепить много потоков и писать руками на ассемблере, но сортировка, например, перебором всех перестановок с проверкой, а не получился ли наконец отсортированный массив, никогда не обгонит даже сортировку вставками/выбором. Если вы увер... знаете, что лучшего алгоритма нет - только тогда надо искать самое узкое место программы, профилировать...

Comment: Надо смотреть на алгоритм. Затем pypy, numba, разные библиотеки (numpy, scipy, ...). Когда эти возможности будут исчерпаны, портировать.

Comment: У меня программа постоянно делает скриншот ImageGrab.Grab (Pillow) и ищет белые пиксели в определенной области, а дальше если их количество превышает 90000, то выполняет пару кликов. Испльзую Pillow, Numpy, Win32api, threading

Comment: в математических вычислениях threading?

Comment: Нет, там несколько позиций надо просматривать, вот я это и делал с помощью threading, сейчас переделал с использованием asyncio, стало быстрее работать